# Angular 2 : Stop propagation of parent element's event , when clicking on link

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml, angular2-template, event-bubbling

I have a case of event bubbling. Example :

```
<td (click)="doSomething()">
  <text [innerHtml]="content"> 
        //  content of innerHtml is :  <a href="http://google.com"></a>
  </text>
</td>
```

The  tag is rendered from another component through innerHtml. The problem:  when i click on the  link, the click event of  element is fired also. How to solve the problem (stop the propagation of doSomething()), knowing that event handlers(or any angular 2 code ) can't be passed through innerHtml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

**Workaround** could be simply placing `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` over `text` component, so that event will not get bubbled up from hosting component. Same thing can be improvise by writing a `Directive`.

```
<td (click)="doSomething()">
  <text (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" [innerHtml]="content"> 
        //  content of innerHtml is :  <a href="http://google.com"></a>
  </text>
</td>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can take advantage of bubbling. From your handler you can look at `event.target` to see if an `A` was clicked, and if so, skip your action.

Be careful, though, because `event.target` may be the `SPAN`! You need to not just check if the event's target is an `A` tag, but also walk up the DOM tree in a simple simulation of bubbling.

So here's possible solution:

**template**

```
(click)="doSomething($event)"
```

**component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  content = '<a href="http://google.com">Link text <span>Nested text</span></a>'

  doSomething(e) {
    let target = e.target;

    while (target !== e.currentTarget) {
      if (target.tagName == 'A') return;
      target = target.parentNode;
    }

    alert('do something')
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nSQHuHbGQVx0uotXezUE?p=preview)**

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$event` object as below:

```
<a (click)="stopPropagation($event);false"     //<<<----added click event
    href="http://google.com">
</a>

stopPropagation(event: Event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

Comment: ```;false"``` 

Is the important factor here. Worked like a charm. ++

Answer (score 2):

(click)="$event.stopPropagation()" worked for me, earlier i was trying without "$" it was not working at that time.